# Meteor app open URL in chrome browser on Android

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, meteor

For a Meteor app, on Android/Cordova we need to create a url link button for the user that, when clicked, will open up a URL in a chrome browser (as opposed to opening it within the app itself) and pass a parameter to it (the user ID).  Is there a Meteor package to do this (couldn't find one)?  Is there simple js to do this (couldn't get js from other similar SO questions to work in this context)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If know you are on android, use the Intent syntax URL

```
intent:host/a/path/#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.android.chrome;end
```

Try on the [demo page](https://jsbin.com/lesequ/latest):

```
<h2>Launch in Chrome Stable</h2>
<a href="intent:www.xhaus.com/headers#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.android.chrome;end">Open</a>

<h2>Launch in Chrome Beta</h2>
<a href="intent:www.xhaus.com/headers#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.chrome.beta;end">Open</a>
```

Comment: Great.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for this package: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser. Once installed, you can [open a link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#cordovainappbrowseropen) in the system browser (chrome), by using `_system` as the target:

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, "_system", options);
```

However, even without this package you should be able to do what you want like this:

```
window.open(url, '_system');
```

Comment: Great.  Thanks.  How do you specify that the browser that comes up will be Chrome?

Comment: You can't. But if you configure your system browser to be Chrome then it will. If you cannot be certain of that, then you can consider using crosswalk (a package that makes your webview use a recent fork of chrome).

Comment: We're already using Crosswalk.  However, we need to make sure that the external browser that someone is directed to will be Chrome.  Any insight?  Thanks again for your help.